# Laptop won't boot elementary os

Tags: ssd

So I installed an mstata SSD in my laptop and installed elementary os. It works fine until I put my old hard drive back in. Even with nothing on the HD my system will not longer boot.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a BIOS boot priority if the only actual change is the presence of the drive. When you turn the machine on there should be an option to hit one of the F1-F12 keys mentioned on the boot screen. Hope this helps! Also, the bootloader that installed for me with Loki gives "boot options" on the list of possible devices.